# Find equation of curve based on points

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Given a set of points on a curve, how can I use them to find the function of the curve? Then given a point on that curve and the function, how can I find the next point of distance equal to the distance between the other points?

Comment: Could you clarify ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for Lagrange interpolation: given $n$ points
$(x_1,y_1)\ldots (x_n,y_n)$, with all the $x$'s different, find a polynomial of
degree $n$ passing through all these points. Lagrange's formula is:
$$f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(x-x_1)\cdots(x-x_{i-1})(x-x_{i+1})\cdots(x-x_n)}
{(x_i-x_1)\cdots(x_i-x_{i-1})(x_i-x_{i+1})\cdots(x-x_n)}y_i$$
Note how every term except one is zero when $x=x_i$, and that term gives the value $y_i$.